# Using Τask.Υield to allow socket tasks to run async

Tags: c#, async-await, tcpclient

My question is when performing actions such as connecting to and receiving data from TCP sockets is `Τask.Υield` a suitable way to ensure these happen while allowing the main thread to continue?

In my example I have an automation code that can be connecting to 200 devices via TCP, and sometimes they may be offline resulting in longer timeouts. I want the main thread that called the connect method to continue on with other tasks while all these sockets connect.

```cs
public async Task<bool> Connect()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    _disconnected = false;
    _client = new TcpClient();
    try
    {
        _client.Connect(_ipAddress, _port);
        _failure = false;
        _stream = _client.GetStream();
        Connected?.Invoke(this, true);
        var ReceivingThread = new Thread(Receive);
        ReceivingThread.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (!_failure)
        {
            ErrorLog.Notice($"Failed to connect to {_ipAddress}");
        }
        _failure = true;
        _ = Connect();
    }
    return (!_failure);
}
```

Comment: Use async api of you want it async.

Comment: I'd also suggest to not retry recursively. Maybe even consider Polly.

Comment: @Fildor but I want it to continue trying forever. This is a system that runs forever and will occasionally have devices that go offline for unknown amounts of time.

Comment: You _will_ run into a Stackoverflow if you do it recursively, though. You can perfectly well do it in a loop. Or have a RetryForever Polly Policy ...

Comment: I will definitely have a look at polly. Because I'm not awaiting the recursion will it stack overflow or will it just use more memory until its exhausted? Once a connection is made would it not return and free up all the memory?
Also I will have to be conscious of resource usage by polly as I may have 1-200 instances of TCP clients. I will do some testing! Thank you.

Comment: Your title makes me think you're conflating asynchronicity with multithreading.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama not at all. Waiting for sockets to connect, and waiting for devices to send me info is not a CPU intensive task and doesn't require a thread to perform while the main thread continues. Async is perfectly fine here, I just needed it to hand the thread back over to the main to continue dispatching connection commands and not wait for each device to connect before going to the next. The other comments and answers here were suitable and the Answer i posted is performing exactly how I wanted it to. The Yield also performed suitably however I didn't know if it was a suitable use.

Comment: _"Waiting for sockets to connect, and waiting for devices to send me info is not a CPU intensive task and doesn't require a thread to perform while the main thread continues."_ - but you're using synchronous methods which cause the CPU to wait.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama that is why I had it within an async function and started with a yield. I am programming within a sandbox with proprietary libraries and asynchronous methods are not always available to me. This occasion they were and the answers show this method modified.

Comment: _"that is why I had it within an async function and started with a yield"_ - the `async` keyword simply allows you to use `await`. All the method in your code above does it cause the CPU to wait but on a different thread. It doesn't unblock the CPU so that more work can be done. If this were a web application, I'd be very worried about the code above causing the thread pool to be exhausted thereby preventing new requests from being processed.

Comment: It is not a web application and is run once per device on system startup and in subsequent reconnections of the device gets restarted. The above code allows the cpu to continue starting connects for other devices while waiting for earlier ones to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with this after comments from Fildor. Test fantastic for 10 hours with 100 clients retrying every 1 second.

```cs
public async Task<bool> Connect()
{
    _client = new TcpClient();
    _disconnected = false;
    await Policy.Handle<Exception>(e => !_disconnected)
        .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync(_ => (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)), 
            (exception, waitDuration) => {
                if (!_failure)
                {
                    ErrorLog.Notice($"Failed to connect to 
                        {_ipAddress}");
                }
                _failure = true;
            })
            .ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(() => 
                _client.ConnectAsync(_ipAddress, _port));
    if(!_disconnected)
    {
        _failure = false;
        _stream = _client.GetStream();
        Connected?.Invoke(this, true);
        Receive();
    }
    return !_failure;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, `await Task.Yield()` will not give a guarantee that execution will not continue on the calling thread.
All depends of the current `SynchronizationContext`. If it is exists, then you will continue on the main thread after `await`. If `SynchronizationContext` does not exists, then most probably you will continue on the thread pool.

`SynchronizationContext` exists by default for UI thread in WinForms/WPF and does not exists for ASP Core.

You can prevent capturing the `SynchronizationContext` by using `ConfigureAwait(false)` (but it's not available for `Task.Yield`, but only for "ordinal" tasks).

You can also use `Task.Run` to explicitly offload any work to the thread pool and do not block main thread.

Or you can use the following trick inspired by Microsoft internal implementation found on github.

```
readonly struct EscapeAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
{
  public bool IsCompleted
    => SynchronizationContext.Current == null &&
       TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default;

  public void GetResult() { }

  public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    => Task.Run(continuation);

  public void UnsafeOnCompleted(Action continuation)
    => ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => ((Action)state!)(), continuation);
}

readonly struct EscapeAwaitable
{
  public EscapeAwaiter GetAwaiter() => new EscapeAwaiter();
}

static class TaskEx
{
  public static EscapeAwaitable EscapeContext() => new EscapeAwaitable();
}
```

Usage:

```
async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    await TaskEx.EscapeContext();
    //other async code, which will execute without SynchronizationContext.
}
```

Additionally I would like to suggest to use `ConnectAsync(), GetStreamAsync()` and other async methods of `TcpClient` to not block a thread (even it's thread pool's thread) when waiting for I/O.

Comment: Thank you for the information provided. I am running this on a proprietary processor which wraps the code within mono on a Linux base. I must use .Net framework 4.7.2 so I'm not sure about the `SynchronizationContext` and will have to do some reading.

Comment: In most cases you can just check `SynchronizationContext.Current` in the main thread and if it is `null`, then there is no synchronization context present in your environment.